# Не работает инкремент в Java

Tags: java, инкремент

Доброго времени суток! Только начал изучать Java и столкнулся с такой проблемой: не работают конструкции вида i++ даже в самом примитивном коде, хотя i+1 отрабатывается верно. Например:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        i = i++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится "5", а если заменить на `i+1`, то выводится "6". Это баг, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструкция `i = i++` приведёт к присвоению переменной её значения до инкремента. Либо используйте префиксную форму `i = ++i`, либо вообще уберите присваивание. Оператор инкремента работает и без него, просто

```
int i = 5;
i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Вы не уловили тонкость вопроса..... да, i = i++ приведёт к присвоению переменной её значения до инкремента, но  и  в выражении участвует одна и та же переменная, что по логике должно было привести к её увеличению опосля... Думаю это смущает автора

Comment: Спасибо, теперь разобрался!